# Как найти кнопку, принадлежащую строке с определенным именем в столбце, используя XPath?

Tags: html, xpath

Как мне найти кнопку, которая находится в одной строке с именем "Lois" используя XPath

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Add a border to a table:</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td><button type="button">Click!</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
        <td><button type="button">Click!</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Найти не ячейку а кнопку с именем ячейки в первом столбце с именем Lois

Comment: Мне кажется, не хватает входных условий: 1) будет ли меняться или динамическая структура документа (положение таблицы с данными в документе) 2) будет ли меняться (или динамическая) структура данных в самой таблице (например, имена будут не в первой, а второй ячейке, или вообще в одной строке так, в другой - по другому)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Простой вариант** - таблица как на картинке из 3 столбцов, поиск состоит из двух этапов:

- находим столбец ячейки, который содержит имя "Lois"

  ```
  .//tr/td[text()[.="Lois"]]
  ```
- Принимаем, что структура таблицы постоянна и получаем второй элемент-родственник относительно столбца "Lois" и его кнопку

  ```
  .//tr/td[text()[.="Lois"]]/following-sibling::td[position()=2]/button
  ```

**Второй вариант** - если длина таблицы неограничена (кроме имени и фамилии будет куча других параметров), но "Имя" будет начинать строку, а "Кнопка" - заканчивать, мы можем взять последний элемент, который соответствует кнопке:

```
    .//tr/td[text()[.="Lois"]]/following-sibling::td[last()]/button
```

Самый **универсальный вариант**, когда мы не зависим от положения ячейки имени и кнопки

```
   .//tr[td[text()[.="Lois"]]]/td/button
```

На еще **более универсальный вариант** натолкнул комментарий [lospejos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204287/lospejos).

Учитываем, что имя "Lois" соответствует столбцу "Firstname", а не какому-нибудь другому. Мы находим позицию заголовка "Firstname" (позиция 1) с помощью запроса

```
  count(tr/th/text()[.="Firstname"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

и используем ее для поиска имени "Lois" в строке

```
  .//tr[td[count(tr/th/text()[.="Firstname"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1][text()[.="Lois"]]]/td/button
```

что, с учетом вычисленного count, для машины выглядит так

```
 .//tr[td[1][text()[.="Lois"]]]/td/button
```

то есть наш элемент должен соответствовать двум условиям - находится под заголовком "Firstname"  и иметь имя "Lois"

Comment: Универсальный вариант, ИМХО, не такой уж и универсальный: например, если значение "Lois" будет в колонке с фамилией :-) Я не критикую, просто уточняю :-)

Comment: @lospejos Это не имеет разницы, хоть в колонке с ростом, вопрос стоит - "с определенным именем в столбце", столбец содержит "Lois", значит наш клиент

Comment: @lospejos вы меня заставили найти более продвинутое решение

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR;

Находим элемент кнопки:

```
/html/body/table/tr[td[1]/text()='Lois' and td[2]/text()='Griffin']/td/button
```

Находим элемент ячейки (с кнопкой):

```
/html/body/table/tr[td[1]/text()='Lois' and td[2]/text()='Griffin']/td
```

Хочу заметить, что в этом ответе допущение о том, что в первой ячейке каждой строки таблицы содержится имя, а во второй - фамилия. Если структура таблицы будет динамической, необходимо применять более интеллектуальный алгоритм поиска.

Comment: Можно ограничиться условием tr[td[1]/text()='Lois' , этого достаточно

Comment: Не помогло. А как пользоваться условием?

Comment: @Loligan под условием я подразумеваю выражения между [ ] -скобками. например, такое выражение даст аналогичный результат .//tr[td[1]/text()='Lois']/td/button. посмотрите ниже мое решение, оно охватывает многие случаи поиска

Comment: @Loligan а как именно "не помогло"? Не возвращает ожидаемые результаты? Я тестировал на OxygenXML, у меня  корректно вернуло. Конечно, если у вас по структуре документ не отличается

Comment: @lospejos я думаю, он просто xpath сделал так tr[td[1]/text()='Lois' , а не в выражении - пожтому не помогло